# how to multiply 2D slices of two 3D matrices with each other in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two 3D matrices **A(kl,1,r)** and **B(1,rs,r)**.  **kl=rs**.
I need to get a new matrix **C(kl,rs,r)** which should have  the product of column vector of **A(kl,1)** by the row vector of **B(1,rs)** for every page **r** without for loop

```
C=zeros(size(A,1),size(B,2),r);
for rr=1:size(A,3)
    dummy=squeeze(A(:,:,rr))*squeeze(B(:,:,rr))';
    C(:,:,rr)=dummy;
end
```

can anyone help with that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bsxfun`, you could do that directly in one line

```
out = bsxfun(@times, A, B);
```

**Sample Inputs:**

```
>> A

A(:,:,1) =

 6
10
 3

A(:,:,2) =

 2
 2
 1

>> B

B(:,:,1) =

 5     5     4

B(:,:,2) =

 8     7     8
```

**Results:**

```
out(:,:,1) =

30    30    24
50    50    40
15    15    12


out(:,:,2) =

16    14    16
16    14    16
 8     7     8
```